# Vue transition list with mutual exclusive elements

Tags: javascript, vue.js, transition

I'm animating a list with `transition-group` in my app.
This list is filtered by a `select` input. The select is either selecting all of them or selecting mutual exclusive groups. This kinda breaks the transition badly.
I think I would need something like Transition Modes to make it work, but [VueJS docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions) states that:

> Transition modes are not available (for transition-group), because we are no longer alternating between mutually exclusive elements.

Here's an example code:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
  <select v-model="filter">
    <option v-for="(o, i) in filterOptions" :key="`o-${i}`" :value="o"> {{ o }}</option>
  </select>

  <table>
    <transition-group name="fade" tag="ul">
      <li v-for="t in filteredRows" :key="t.label">{{ t.label }} - {{ t.prop }}</li>
    </transition-group>
  </table>

</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    filter: 'all',
    filterOptions: ['all', 'p1', 'p2'],
    rows: [
        {
        label: 'Row 1',
        prop: 'p1'
      },
      {
        label: 'Row 2',
        prop: 'p1'
      },
      {
        label: 'Row 3',
        prop: 'p2'
      },
      {
        label: 'Row 4',
        prop: 'p2'
      },
    ]
  },
  computed: {
    filteredRows: function() {
        return this.rows.filter(o => o.prop === this.filter || this.filter === 'all');
    }
  }
})

.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active,
.fade-move {
  transition: all .5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

li {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

And here's a fiddle with it: https://jsfiddle.net/0v6pa8tk/

When selecting between `p1` and `p2` we can see the animation is clumsy.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [vertical translation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Entering-Leaving-Transitions):

```
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active,
.fade-move {
  transition: all .5s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to
{
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}

.fade-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}

li {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/p36xe0qt/ ]